# Using a block to clean map in ruby

Tags: ruby, block

I have this line:

```
my_array.map do |x| 
  if x.to_i == 0
    x.starts_with?("new") ? x[3..-1] : ''
  else
    Tag.find(x).name
  end
end
```

I'd like to clean this up, and move the block to a function where I can reuse it.

How would I do this? Should I write a block inside a function? or a regular function, but how would I use `map`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to "move a block" is just to make it a method.

```
def foo x
  if x.to_i == 0
    x.starts_with?("new") ? x[3..-1] : ''
  else
   Tag.find(x).name
  end
end      


my_array.map { |x| foo(x) }
```

Comment: when would it be better to write a block and yield to it?

Comment: You are missing an `end`.

Comment: @NickGinanto When you don't expect to reuse any part of the block.

Comment: @NickGinanto: If only part of a block's logic is sharable, you might write an alternative to `.map` which implements the shared part, then also yields to a (smaller, non-shared) block.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda version is also possible if you like the syntax better:

```
name_of_item = ->(item) do # use "lambda do |item|" in older versions of ruby.
  if item.to_i == 0
    item.starts_with?("new") ? x[3..-1] : ''
  else
   Tag.find(item).name
  end
end 

my_array.map &name_of_item
```

Comment: Anonymous functions aren't as common in ruby as they in javascript. Can you give a practical example of where it might appear?